# Converting cordova project using VS 2015 certificate issue

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, visual-studio-2015

Does any one know how to assign the certificate file to the project while creating the Windows app package.

Basically i have a cordova Ionic project which was already developed and now to make a windows app, i used VS 2015 --new project option from existing code. after few hiccups am able to run the windows app,

however am not able to figure out where to add/assign the certificate which i want to use with this package.
am even trying to find where is the app manifest file however not luck in finding it, i can see config.xml.

Appreciate your help.
Regards,
RK.

Answer (score 0):

> Does any one know how to assign the certificate file to the project while creating the Windows app package.

If you haven't got a certificate file, you should create one(.pfx file). You can follow [How to create an app package signing certificate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj835832(v=vs.85).aspx) to create one.

Once you got the certificate. You can sign your app by modifying the `build.json` file. You can refer to [Sign Windows App](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/win8/index.html#signing-an-app) for details.